# Is this capacitor graph safe to be constructed?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, capacitor, current

[image]

Above is the power vs time graph of a capacitor charging & discharging in a rectifier circuit. It spikes between 350 W and -140 W, which is extremely high. However, the average is only 2.7158 W.

Can I just look at the average power to determine whether a capacitor is safe since it is oscillating or do I have to look at the maximum spikes and minimum spikes to determine whether a capacitor is safe to use?

Comment: I think you should show the whole circuit.  The measurements may not be representative, or they may be showing something other than what you intended.  Simulators are wonderful things, but you have to be sure you are using them correctly.

Comment: Also define what you mean by "safe." Safe for human life, for the capacitor, for downstream components/equipment?

Answer (score 3):

Just visually, that is a LOT more than 2.7W RMS. The capacitor also needs to be characterized for maximum safe ripple current, and [ESR (Equivalent series resistance)](https://www.avnet.com/wps/portal/abacus/resources/article/understanding-esr-in-electrolytic-capacitors/).

Comment: Note that you may be able to reach a safe ripple current and ESR by using multiple, smaller-value capacitors in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the average, you want the RMS. By a simply multiply like you are doing, you are generating negative values (note how the power goes close to -140W) which would imply the capacitor absorbing rather than radiating energy as if it were super-cold or something, so the average is pretty small (the average of +1000 and -1000 is zero as an example).

RMS makes sure all the radiant energy is positive so you don't get that error, that's why power is often described as RMS. (e.g. a loudspeaker rated for 100W RMS)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square

Comment: I'm afraid that even if often (ab)used RMS power has something ranging from very little to no use at all. Root mean square meaningful applies to voltage and current instead while the "good" power is the average one.

Answer (score 0):

You do have to look at the current through the capacitor. High **ripple currents** can cause capacitors to fail by overheating. Voltage is irrelevant here.

The average signed power through a capacitor, over a long enough time period, is equal to the amount of power loss in the capacitor. 2.7W is quite a lot and will get any small component very hot. Though it is also possible that you didn't use a long enough time period to calculate the average.